# Нужно ли слово "типа" выделять запятыми?

Tags: пунктуация, жаргон

**Это я типа работаю.**

Нужно ли слово "типа" выделять запятыми?

Answer (score 1):

Не надо. Это типа неопределенного артикля. (Определенный – "конкретно").

Вы же не выделяете запятыми "как бы"? Или, как модно сейчас писать: какбэ.

Comment: И даже не так, а: каГбэ.